# How to make a graph from function output in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm completely lost at this using MATLAB functions, so here is the case:
lets assume I have SUM=0, and
I have a constant probability P that the user gives me, and I have to compare this constant P, with other M (also user gives M) random probabilities, if P is larger I add 1 to SUM, if P is smaller I add -1 to SUM... and at the end I want print on the screen the graph of the process.

I managed till now to make only one stage with this code:

```
function [result] = ex1(p)
if (rand>=p) result=1;
else result=-1;
end
```

(its like M=1)

How do You suggest I can modify this code in order to make it work the way I described it before (including getting a graph) ?

Or maybe I'm getting the logic wrong? the question says I get 1 with probability P, and -1 with probability (1-P), and the SUM is the same

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
p = 0.25; % example data
M = 20; % example data

random = rand(M,1); % generate values
y = cumsum(2*(random>=p)-1); % compute cumulative sum of +1/-1
plot(y) % do the plot
```

The important function here is [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html),  which does the cumulative sum on the sequence of +1/-1 values generated by `2*(random>=p)-1`.

Example graph with `p=0.5`,  `M=2000`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you achieve your input, but this should get you on the way:

```
p = 0.5;            % Constant probability
m = 10;
randoms = rand(m,1) % Random probabilities

results = ones(m,1);
idx = find(randoms < p)

results(idx) = -1;

plot(cumsum(results))
```

For `m = 1000`:
[image]